After importing KMZ/KML holes do not show up in QGIS
I have a KMZ of a land area, a polygon. That polygon has holes.
When I load the file into QGIS, the holes disappear. This issue was addressed back in 2018 but with no real solution. I also tried the geometry validation, it finds no issue and returns the geometry is valid.
Polygon holes/rings are showing up as polygons in QGIS
The view on GEarth:

The same view on QGIS, no holes:

Is there a tool inside QGIS that can fix this issue?
ArcGIS can render the KML fine and re-export the layer (shapefile for instance) with geometry correction so QGIS can then open it and show the holes. The data is there, somewhere.
I don't have ArcGIS and I want QGIS to be able to deal with this.

Ok, found a solution with the plugin "KML Tools". Importing from that plugin allows QGIS to render holes correctly.
Here is the imported polygon with the right holes inside:

Now I would like to understand why this does not come native inside QGIS's Add layer panel.

It would help a lot if you could share some test data.
